# Inserting new entity does not look at 'SEQUENCE_GENERATOR' - demo admin

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express Edition with hibernate `SQLServer2008Dialect` dialect to run the Admin demo and have some troubles with primary key generation. The initial insert statement do not use the pre-calculated values from `'SEQUENCE_GENERATOR'` for the `@Id` field.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "StructuredContentFieldId")
@GenericGenerator(
    name="StructuredContentFieldId",
    strategy="org.broadleafcommerce.common.persistence.IdOverrideTableGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name="segment_value", value="StructuredContentFieldImpl"),
        @Parameter(name="entity_name", value="org.broadleafcommerce.cms.structure.domain.StructuredContentFieldImpl")
    }
)
@Column(name = "SC_FLD_ID")
protected Long id;
```

When trying to insert new Structured Content, `'SEQUENCE_GENERATOR'` table gets some values populated:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SEQUENCE_GENERATOR

ID_NAME                     ID_VAL
--------------------------- --------------------
SandBoxImpl                 101
StructuredContentFieldImpl  101
StructuredContentImpl       101
```

But the new entity is saved with the id of 1 (there are some existing rows already in this table as per demo sql script):

```
SELECT SC_ID, CONTENT_NAME, SC_TYPE_ID FROM dbo.BLC_SC

SC_ID                CONTENT_NAME                               SC_TYPE_ID
-------------------- ------------------------------------------ --------------------
1                    html test                                  2
100                  Buy One Get One - Twice the Burn           1
[...]
156                  Home Page Featured Products Title          3
```

The following sql shows up in the console when inserting that row:

```
[artifact:mvn] Hibernate: select tbl.ID_VAL from SEQUENCE_GENERATOR tbl with (updlock, rowlock ) where tbl.ID_NAME=?
[artifact:mvn] Hibernate: update SEQUENCE_GENERATOR set ID_VAL=?  where ID_VAL=? and ID_NAME=?
[artifact:mvn] Hibernate: insert into BLC_SC (ARCHIVED_FLAG, CREATED_BY, DATE_CREATED, DATE_UPDATED, UPDATED_BY, CONTENT_NAME, DELETED_FLAG, LOCALE_CODE, LOCKED_FLAG, OFFLINE_FLAG, ORIG_ITEM_ID, ORIG_SANDBOX_ID, PRIORITY, SANDBOX_ID, SC_TYPE_ID, SC_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Later on saving some HTML content into the `BLC_SC_FLD` isn't that lucky. New entity also gets assigned the id of 1, which unfortunately already exists:

```
SELECT SC_FLD_ID, FLD_KEY, VALUE, SC_ID FROM dbo.BLC_SC_FLD    

SC_FLD_ID     FLD_KEY       VALUE                                         SC_ID
------------- ------------- --------------------------------------------- --------
1             imageUrl      /img/banners/buy-one-get-one-home-banner.jpg  100
```

and of course the exception is thrown:

```
[artifact:mvn] Hibernate: update SEQUENCE_GENERATOR set ID_VAL=?  where ID_VAL=? and ID_NAME=?      
[artifact:mvn] Hibernate: insert into BLC_SC_FLD (CREATED_BY, DATE_CREATED, DATE_UPDATED, UPDATED_BY, FLD_KEY, LOB_VALUE, VALUE, SC_ID, SC_FLD_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[artifact:mvn] 2014-05-06 00:58:02.191:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/admin/structured-content/1
[artifact:mvn] org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BLC_SC_F__8A534C1863E06FD9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BLC_SC_FLD'. The duplicate key value is (1).; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BLC_SC_F__8A534C1863E06FD9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BLC_SC_FLD'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

I am not sure where is the problem. The `@GenericGenerator` generation strategy `org.broadleafcommerce.common.persistence.IdOverrideTableGenerator` seems to hit `'SEQUENCE_GENERATOR'` on first insert and then increments the id from `FIELD_CACHE` variable as designed.

So I have actually 2 questions.

1. Why `'SEQUENCE_GENERATOR'` gets initial values of 101, when there is already higher id saved in the table?
2. Why the entity is being saved with the value of 1? Is this MS SQL Server related?

Answer (score 1):

Ok resolved :) Broadleaf has 3 persistence units, and by default they point to the same database, but only one (`blPU`) persistence unit imports sql at the start of the demo.

So by doing this:

```
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
blCMSStorage.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
blSecurePU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

I made the `SEQUENCE_GENERATOR` to be dropped and recreated empty by other persistence unit in line.

This works fine:

```
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
blCMSStorage.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
blSecurePU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Dooh!